# PBS running multiple instances of the same program with different arguments

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, pbs, serial-processing

How do you go about running the same program multiple times but with different arguments each instance on a cluster, submitted through a PBS. Also, is it possible to designate each of these programs to a separate node? Currently, if I have a PBS with the following script:

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
/myscript
```

it will run the single program once, on a single node. If I use the following script:

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
/mscript -arg arg1 &
/myscript -arg arg2
```

I believe this will run each program in serial, but it will use only one node. Can I declare multiple nodes and then delegate specific ones out to each instance of the program I wish to run?

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciate. I apologize if I am not clear on anything or am using incorrect terminology...I am very new to cluster computing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do that using a form of MPI. MPI stands for message passing interface and there are a number of libraries out there that implement the interface. I would recommend using OpenMPI as it integrates very well with PBS. As you say you are new, you might appreciate this [tutorial.](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/)

Answer (score 0):

`GNU Parallel` would be ideal for this purpose. An example PBS script for your case:

```
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=4 # set ppn for however many cores per node on your cluster
#Other PBS directives

module load gnu-parallel   # this will depend on your cluster setup

parallel -j4 --sshloginfile $PBS_NODEFILE /mscript -arg {} \
  ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8
```

`GNU Parallel` will handle ssh connections to the various nodes. I've written out the example with arguments on the command line, but you'd probably want to read the arguments from a text file. Here are links to the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) and [tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). Option `-j4` should match the ppn (number of cores per node).